# How to read rdf:description inside annotation using OWL API

Tags: java, rdf, owl, owl-api

I am new to the OWL API. How can I get the value inside the `rdfs:label` in the following OWL file?
`oboInOwl:hasSynonym` is an annotation property.

```xml
<oboInOwl:hasSynonym>
  <rdf:Description>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&oboInOwl;Synonym"/>
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Endocardiums</rdfs:label>
  </rdf:Description>
</oboInOwl:hasSynonym>
```

I am using Owl API. I do not want to use XML parsers.

Comment: I think you'll need to show more of the ontology.  The fragment you've shown is only part of a triple.  `oboInOwl:hasSynonym` is a property, and the object is a blank node with an `rdf:type` and `rdfs:label`.  Knowing what the _subject_ of the triple is might help, because then we could identify it as an individual and ask about its properties.

Answer (score 3):

Here's code that recreates an ontology containing the type of structure that you've described, and shows how to retrieve the annotation property value that you're interested in.  `getSampleOntology()` creates the ontology (and prints it), and the `main` shows how you can start from `x`, find its `hasSynonym` values, and then find the `rdfs:label`s of those values.  This is based on the [OWL API code examples](http://sourceforge.net/p/owlapi/code/ci/aef6981535f07a2d0d44c394b9f4d5415f36025a/tree/contract/src/test/java/org/coode/owlapi/examples/Examples.java#l1242) from the documentation.

```
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.OWLOntologyDocumentTarget;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.RDFXMLOntologyFormat;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.SystemOutDocumentTarget;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.IRI;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLAnnotation;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLAnnotationAssertionAxiom;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLAnnotationProperty;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLAnnotationSubject;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLAnonymousIndividual;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLAxiom;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLDataFactory;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLIndividual;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLNamedIndividual;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLObjectProperty;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLObjectPropertyAssertionAxiom;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyCreationException;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyFormat;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyStorageException;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.vocab.OWLRDFVocabulary;

public class OWLAPIAnnotations {
    final static OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
    final static OWLDataFactory factory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
    final static String ns = "http://example.org/";
    final static OWLNamedIndividual x = factory.getOWLNamedIndividual( IRI.create( ns+"x" ));
    final static OWLAnonymousIndividual y = factory.getOWLAnonymousIndividual();
    final static OWLObjectProperty hasSynonym = factory.getOWLObjectProperty(IRI.create(ns + "hasSynonym"));

    public static OWLOntology getSampleOntology() throws OWLOntologyCreationException, OWLOntologyStorageException {
        OWLOntology ontology = manager.createOntology();
        manager.addAxiom( ontology, factory.getOWLClassAssertionAxiom( factory.getOWLClass(IRI.create(ns + "Synonym")), y));
        manager.addAxiom(ontology, factory.getOWLObjectPropertyAssertionAxiom(hasSynonym, x, y));
        OWLAnnotation ann = factory.getOWLAnnotation( factory.getOWLAnnotationProperty(OWLRDFVocabulary.RDFS_LABEL.getIRI()), factory.getOWLLiteral("Endocardium", "en"));
        manager.addAxiom(ontology, factory.getOWLAnnotationAssertionAxiom(y, ann));
        manager.saveOntology(ontology, System.out);
        return ontology;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws OWLOntologyCreationException, OWLOntologyStorageException {
        OWLOntology ontology = getSampleOntology();
        for( OWLIndividual object : x.getObjectPropertyValues( hasSynonym, ontology ) ) {
            for ( OWLAnnotationAssertionAxiom aAxiom : ontology.getAnnotationAssertionAxioms( (OWLAnnotationSubject) object ) ) {
                if ( aAxiom.getProperty().equals( factory.getRDFSLabel() ) ) {
                    System.out.println( aAxiom.getValue() );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output at the end (which shows that annotation value) is:

```
"Endocardium"@en
```

The ontology that is generated is (with comments removed, for space):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xml:base="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:example="http://example.org/">
    <ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://example.org/hasSynonym"/>
    <Class rdf:about="http://example.org/Synonym"/>
    <NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://example.org/x">
        <example:hasSynonym>
            <rdf:Description>
                <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://example.org/Synonym"/>
                <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Endocardium</rdfs:label>
            </rdf:Description>
        </example:hasSynonym>
    </NamedIndividual>
</rdf:RDF>
```